# Trigger vs Event Trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, difference, eventtrigger

I am a beginner of learning trigger, I found that there have Trigger and Event Trigger in Postgresql, I want to know what's the difference between Trigger and Event Trigger? And what's the application scenario of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ("traditional") trigger is fired by DML statements: `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`

An event trigger is fired for DDL statements: `create table`, `drop table` or similar statements.

So the first catches changes to the data, the second catches changes to the data *definition*

Answer (score -1):

A [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html):

- can run the PL/pgSQL trigger function in the database. *A SQL trigger function and trigger procedure don't exist.
- is fired when `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` operation happens or is prevented on a table or view in the database.

An [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html):

- can run the PL/pgSQL event trigger function in the database. *A SQL event trigger function and event trigger procedure don't exist.
- is fired when `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `SECURITY LABEL`, `COMMENT`, `GRANT`, `REVOKE` or `SELECT INTO` happens in the database.